# Разница между текстовым и бинарным способом доступа к файлу

Tags: c, файлы

1. Есть ли какая-то разница между текстовым и бинарным доступом к файлу в С кроме как на Windows преобразований связанных с `\r\n`?
2. Функция `fopen()` может содержать второй аргумент `t` или `b` режим, но какая между ними разница?
3. `fread()` и `fwrite()` всегда интерпретируют информацию в бинарном формате?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Нет. Но такое преобразование не только в Windows; возможны и другие операционные системы, где требуется *подобное* преобразование (не обязательно `\r\n`, как в Windows, DOS, OS/2 - насколько я помню, в Mac'ах было `\n\r`, но могу и ошибаться).
2. Такая, как описано в пункте 1 - обработка символов перевода строки.
3. Нет, в зависимости от режима открытия файла.